# In solaris, how monitor & auto-respond to critical events

Tags: web-server, monitoring, opensolaris, joyent

I have a website that randomly fail. Is running in open solaris on joyent.

I have a monitoring service that alert me when the site is down, but, I want a way to put a "insider" tool that tell me why that happened.

Is because the cpu is too high? Not memory? Which process fail? Is possible to have a backtrace of that?

Everything is running on the Solaris Service Management Facility. The webserver is cherokee, the database is mysql and the language is python/django.

I want the most simple setup to monitor that & auto-respond , ie: restart the webserver or the django process in case of failure.

I prefer a low-overhead tool. I don't need the fancy monitoring that some tools have, no ned graphs or sms alert. Only know what fail, restart it if possible (maybe up to n times), and have a log somewhere when I will check it.

Comment: If everything is running on SMF, as you wrote, you already have the logging, monitoring and restart facilities or am I missing something ?

Comment: Well, any way to see that info? I have not expertise in solaris admin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also choose to implement additional monitoring with Nodefly, NewRelic, Pagerduty, Pingdom, or any of nagios, Munin, or zabbix.

You have a *lot* of choices available.

Answer (score 1):

All of your needs can be met by the logs in /var/svc/log.

Those are the logs for everything SMF is doing to your system, behind the scenes.

Extracting the 'interesting' data is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Look into collectd. I've gotten it to compile on illumos/smartos. Also:

https://github.com/gflarity/nervous and https://github.com/gflarity/response